# How to get cart items id except configurable product

Tags: magento-1.8

I have add a configure product in magento store which has associated products( simple and downloaded both) in admin. From frontend I add simple associated product in cart and get cart items information using following code:

```
$cart_items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
foreach( $cart_items as $items )
{
   $items->getProductId();
}
```

At this time there is only one product in cart ( simple associated product ) but above code return id "95" and "96" where 95 for configurable product and 96 for simple associated product.

How to get only simple associated product id?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `$items->getParentItemId()` to distinguish between children and parent items.

Parent items have a zero-value parent item id.

Inserting a configured product in cart will result in a parent quote item (referring to the configurable product) plus a child quote item (referring to the simple product which represents the user choice).

Hope it helps.

Kind regards,
Alessandro

Comment: Thanks.. it works but there is a problem that `$items->getQty();` always return "float(1)" while more than 1 quantity add in cart for child product.How to get correct quantity for child product?

Answer (score 1):

When you invoke `getAllItems()`, it returns *all* quote items (parents and children). If you want just the items added (Magento adds the parent product when you add a child product) and shown in your cart, you need `getAllVisibleItems()`.

```
$cart_items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
```

This will return just the simple product you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
$cart_items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
foreach( $cart_items as $items )
{
     if($itemts->getTypeId() != 'configurable')
     {
            $items->getProductId();
      }
}
```

the above  should resolve your issue for you

Comment: Just a hint: use Product Type constants instead of hardcoded strings; you can find them in `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type`

Comment: Normally i do this was for ease of clarity.

Comment: Thanks for give me a hint. but in my case `if($items->getProductType() != 'configurable'){$productid = $items->getProductId();}` is working.