# How to get correct quantity for child product in cart

Tags: magento-1.7, shopping-cart

I use following code to get cart information:

```
$cart_items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
foreach( $cart_items as $items )
{
        $items->getQty();
}
```

In above code `$items->getQty()` always return "float(1)" for child product.

For Example I have a configurable product say "2-disk set" which has associated product as "cds & dvds". I have add quantity 2 for "cds & dvds" in cart but `$items->getQty()` return "float(1)".

How to get correct quantity for child product?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Try `getAllVisibleItems()` function

```
$cart_items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach( $cart_items as $items )
{
        $items->getQty();
}
```

Ref : https://techbandhu.wordpress.com/2013/11/29/magento-what-is-the-difference-between-getallvisibleitems-and-getallitems/

Answer (score 0):

I found my solution from [link](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/59592/how-to-get-cart-items-id-except-configurable-product):

```
$cart_items = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getAllItems();
foreach( $cart_items as $items )
{
    STATIC $qty='';
    if($items->getProductType() == 'configurable')  //configurable products
    {
        $qty = $items->getQty();
        continue;
    }
    else                                            // non-configurable product
    {
        if (!$items->getParentItem())               // products which have not parent product 
        {
            $qty = $items->getQty();
        }
    }
    echo $qty;
}
```